# Angular, "x is not a function" when attempting to use Service

Tags: angularjs, function, service, factory

```
app.service('situacao', function($log, $q, $http, $rootScope){
    var situacao = this; 
    situacao.lista = {};
    situacao.getAllSituacao = function(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        console.log("php/getAll.php");
        $http.get($rootScope.endPoint + "php/getAll.php")
            .success(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            situacao.lista = res;
            defer.resolve(res);
        }).error(function(err, status){
            defer.reject(err);
        }); 
        return defer.promise;
    };
    return situacao;});
    app.controller('listCtrl',['$scope', '$uibModal', '$log', '$http', function(situacao, $scope, $modal, $log, $http) {   
    $scope.init = function(){
        $scope.getAll();
    }
    $scope.getAll = function(){        
        situacao.getAllSituacao().then(function(res){
            //sucess
            $scope.dispSituacao = situacao.lista;  
        }, function(err){
            //error
        })
    };
    $scope.init(); 
}]);
```

I'm trying to use the "service" but results in error:
situacao.getAllSituacao is not a function.

what is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to update your inject to pass it in as well since you're using the array notation:

Change

```
app.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', '$log', '$http', function (situacao, $scope, $modal, $log, $http)
```

To

```
app.controller('listCtrl', ['situacao', '$scope', '$uibModal', '$log', '$http', function (situacao, $scope, $modal, $log, $http) {
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Array notation is important but can trip people up at first.

Comment: Thanks for adding that comment, that helped me!

Comment: JESUS!! I spent so much time on this..  Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

In my situation, I named all injected services correctly, but, their order was not the same, and it gave me the same error. My code was something like this:

```
app.controller('listCtrl', ['situacao', '$scope', '$uibModal', '$log', '$http', function ($scope, situacao, $modal, $log, $http) {}
```

Putting them in correct order solved the problem. Like this:

```
app.controller('listCtrl', ['situacao', '$scope', '$uibModal', '$log', '$http', function (situacao, $scope, $modal, $log, $http) {}
```

Hope this helps someone.